# Pure Java/Scala code for writing Tensorflow TFRecords data file

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, guava, tensorflow

I'm trying to write a pure Java/Scala implementation of the Tensorflow RecordWriter class in order to convert Spark DataFrame into [TFRecords](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/python_io.html#tfrecords-format-details) file. According to the documentation, in TFRecords, each record is formated as follow:

```
uint64 length
uint32 masked_crc32_of_length
byte   data[length]
uint32 masked_crc32_of_data
```

And the CRC mask

```
masked_crc = ((crc >> 15) | (crc << 17)) + 0xa282ead8ul
```

Currently, I compute the CRC with guava implementation with the following code:

```scala
import com.google.common.hash.Hashing

object CRC32 {
  val kMaskDelta = 0xa282ead8

  def hash(in: Array[Byte]): Int = {
    val hashing = Hashing.crc32c()
    hashing.hashBytes(in).asInt()
  }

  def mask(crc: Int): Int ={
    ((crc >> 15) | (crc << 17)) + kMaskDelta
  }
}
```

The rest of my code is:

The data encoding part is done with the following piece of code:

```py
  object LittleEndianEncoding {
   def encodeLong(in: Long): Array[Byte] = {
    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val out = new LittleEndianDataOutputStream(baos)
    out.writeLong(in)
    baos.toByteArray
  }

  def encodeInt(in: Int): Array[Byte] = {
    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val out = new LittleEndianDataOutputStream(baos)

    out.writeInt(in)
    baos.toByteArray
  }
}
```

The record are generated with protocol buffer:

```
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString
import org.tensorflow.example._

import collection.JavaConversions._
import collection.mutable._

object TFRecord {

  def int64Feature(in: Long): Feature = {

    val valueBuilder = Int64List.newBuilder()
    valueBuilder.addValue(in)

    Feature.newBuilder()
      .setInt64List(valueBuilder.build())
      .build()
  }


  def floatFeature(in: Float): Feature = {
    val valueBuilder = FloatList.newBuilder()
    valueBuilder.addValue(in)
    Feature.newBuilder()
      .setFloatList(valueBuilder.build())
      .build()
  }

  def floatVectorFeature(in: Array[Float]): Feature = {
    val valueBuilder = FloatList.newBuilder()
    in.foreach(valueBuilder.addValue)

    Feature.newBuilder()
      .setFloatList(valueBuilder.build())
      .build()
  }

  def bytesFeature(in: Array[Byte]): Feature = {
    val valueBuilder = BytesList.newBuilder()
    valueBuilder.addValue(ByteString.copyFrom(in))
    Feature.newBuilder()
      .setBytesList(valueBuilder.build())
      .build()
  }

  def makeFeatures(features: HashMap[String, Feature]): Features = {
    Features.newBuilder().putAllFeature(features).build()
  }


  def makeExample(features: Features): Example = {
    Example.newBuilder().setFeatures(features).build()
  }

}
```

And here is an example of how I use things together in order to generate my TFRecords file:

```
val label = TFRecord.int64Feature(1)
val feature = TFRecord.floatVectorFeature(Array[Float](1, 2, 3, 4))
val features = TFRecord.makeFeatures(HashMap[String, Feature]  ("feature"->feature, "label"-> label))
val ex = TFRecord.makeExample(features)
val exSerialized = ex.toByteArray()
val length = LittleEndianEncoding.encodeLong(exSerialized.length)
val crcLength =  LittleEndianEncoding.encodeInt(CRC32.mask(CRC32.hash(length)))
val crcEx = LittleEndianEncoding.encodeInt(CRC32.mask(CRC32.hash(exSerialized)))

val out = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.tfrecords"))
out.write(length)
out.write(crcLength)
out.write(exSerialized)
out.write(crcEx)
out.close()
```

When I try to read the file I got inside Tensorflow with [TFRecordReader](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#TFRecordReader), I get the following error:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1076] 0x24cc430 Compute status: Data loss: corrupted record at 0
```

I suspect that the CRC mask computation is not correct or the endianness 
between java and c++ generated file are not the same.

Comment: Where is the error message you are getting?

Comment: When I read the file in tensorflow I get a data corrupted error.

Comment: The mask function is not correct compared to the result obtained with `masked_crc = ((crc >> 15) | (crc << 17)) + 0xa282ead8ul`

Comment: You need to post more details for us to help you Please edit you question and post the error message and the parts of the code that will allow us to regenerate the same error. I am sure some people here can answer the question as it stands, but it would help others if they learned from your situation.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem. The error was in the mask function. The correct mask function is `masked_crc = ((crc >>> 15) | (crc << 17)) + 0xa282ead8` i.e use `>>>` unsigned operator instead `>>`

Answer (score 7):

FWIW, the Tensorflow team has provided utility code for reading/writing TFRecords, which can be [found in the ecosystem repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem/tree/master/hadoop/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/hadoop/util)

Answer (score 6):

The problem with the my implementation is the computation of the CRC mask. Here is fix the I found:

```
def mask(crc: Int): Int ={
    ((crc >>> 15) | (crc << 17)) + kMaskDelta
}
```

The key is the use of the unsigned shift bitwise operator `>>>` instead of `>>`